# RemoteViews addView method does not add listview

Tags: android, android-appwidget, remoteview

I would like to add text view as a header to listview.Here is the code for the layout of the text view text_view_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lay2">
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Header List View"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the code for the listview widget_layout.xml

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/listViewWidget"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
```

Here is the code that I am using for adding text view above listview:

```
RemoteViews remote = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.text_view_layout);
RemoteViews textView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
remote.addView(R.id.lay2, textView);
```

This only shows the text view, not the list view.

Comment: Why do you have the `ListView` in a separate layout? Do you have code for populating the `ListView` with a `RemoteViewsService` and `RemoteViewsFactory`? If so, is that code getting invoked to return the rows for your list?

Comment: I think you are using wrong layouts here.. you use text_view_layout for remote variable and vice versa, widget_layout for textView.. so you are basically trying to add listview into textview?

Comment: I added the list in separte layout because I like to add text view on widget resize

Comment: @Gennadii Saprykin I like to add listview in lay2 layout that is in my text_view_layout

Comment: Another problem with your approach is that there are no sizing/positioning rules for where the `ListView` should go in the `RelativeLayout` this way. Put them all in one layout, and use `setViewVisibility()` to control what should and should not show up.